# why halving happens each 210,000 blocks?

Tags: reward-schedule, time

target time between blocks = 10m
=> 6 blocks per hour
=> 6 * 24 = 144 blocks per day
=> 6 * 24 * 7 = 1,008 blocks per week
=> 6 * 24 * 7 * 52 = 52,416 blocks per year
=> 6 * 24 * 7 * 52 * 4 = 209,664

But halving happened in block 210,000???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you'll get a definitive answer here. It's a constant that was chosen by Satoshi, and without leaving much information about it behind before disappearing.

It's possible that this was chosen in function of the total supply. If the goal was having a limit of 21 million BTC specifically, and starting with a subsidy of 50 BTC/block specifically, then halving every 210000 blocks is correct solution.